# SwiftUI update Elements.count after Network Request

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

i want to update a Custom List with columns.

```
struct XyzView: View {
  @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
  @State var maxrow : Int = 1

init() {
    maxrow = self.maxRow()
}

func maxRow() -> Int {
    let a = self.networkManager.products.count
    return a
}

    var body: some View {
Text("\(maxrow) Elements")

}

}
```

the problem is after network request the count is not updated correctly and reload the view.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.products = products
 }
```

how can i update the view and set maxrow to the current products.count ?
thanks for help.

Comment: Make your NetworkManager `products` property as `@Published` (if it is not) and just use `networkManager.products` somewhere in `body` - view will be updated on network request completed.

Comment: I didn't get that. where are you updating `maxrow` ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini i want to update this guy. (maxrow)

Comment: @Asperi thanks and this is what i have... but the maxrow var is not updating because i need to set max columns in a list and update view after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maxRow` you are using in the `body` is not getting update.
You should bind the view directly to the `products` instead of trying to duplicate it:

```
{
     @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

     var maxRow: Int { networkManager.products.count }

     var body: some View {
         Text("\(maxRow) Elements")
     } 
}
```

Comment: Note that I reduced the code you should use. Always try less code.

Comment: but if i use a custom GRID the var would be loaded to late. 
QGrid(self.networkManager.products, columns: 2,
                              columnsInLandscape: maxRow,
                        vSpacing: 15,
                        hSpacing: 15,
                        vPadding: 0,
                        hPadding: 0) {
                            GridCell(viewModel: ViewModel(product: $0))
                        }

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. what is `GRID` ? and is that related to the original question or it is another one?

Answer (score 0):

In Views it might work more efficient and better to use the `.onAppear` when loading data when displaying a View.

I remade your code to the following:

```
struct XyzView: View {
  @ObservedObject var networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
  @State var maxrow : Int = 1

func maxRow() -> Int {
    let a = self.networkManager.products.count
    return a
}

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(maxrow) Elements")
            .onAppear {
                self.maxrow = self.maxRow()
        }
    }
}
```

This should work like you wanted.

*Tip: If you making any changes in your NetworkManager model, make sure you make all variables `@Published` so the View updates itself.*

Comment: okay thanks . but nothing happens, i tryd this before and in network manager all vars are published.
the onappear fired earlier so the products is still updating and finished later.